# android math doesn't seem to sum up right

Tags: java, android, math

I am tring to calculates win/loss ratio, but when I write the the equason, somehow it becomes zero:
Here is my code:

```
public void count() {
        //int ratio = (wonCount/ (wonCount + lostCount)) * 100;
        long ratio = 2/ (2 + 1) *100;
        timesWon.setText("You Were Right " + wonCount + " Times");
        timesLost.setText("You Were Wrong " + lostCount + " Times");
        statistics.setText("Win/Loss Ratio: " + String.valueOf(ratio) + "%");
        firstTime = false;
    }
```

2/(2+1) *100 = 0 in java. Is there somthing that I'm missing?
thank you.

Comment: if both  operands are integer values, integer calculation is done : `2 / 3` results in `0` || despite some answer suggesting different, `2 / (2+1) * 100` is evaluated as `(2 / (2+1) ) * 100`, that is first the division (after the addition) || if you don't need floating point calculation; do the multiplication first, then the division: `2 * 100 / (2+1)`

Comment: ( or `(100 * wonCount) / (wonCount + lostCount)` )

Comment: See [Int division: Why is the result of 1/3 == 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/int-division-why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java makes the division first, and 2 over 3 is a decimal number that rounded gives 0 in integer representation. Try using floating point data types:

```
Double ratio = 2.0 / (2 + 1) *100;
```

Answer (score -1):

> *"... when I write the the equason, somehow it becomes zero ..."*

This is because *2* divided by *300* is less-than *1*.

Use at least 1 *floating-point* numeric *data-type* for each parenthesized division operation.

```java
double ratio = ((double) wonCount/ (wonCount + lostCount)) * 100;
```

If you're looking for a *[floored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)* value, use the *[Math#floor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double))* method.

```java
long ratio = (long) Math.floor(((double) wonCount/ (wonCount + lostCount)) * 100);
```

Comment: But no one is doing 2 divided by 300.

Comment: @Sören, that doesn't even make sense.

Comment: I should have put "2 divided by 300" in Quotes. Because it was a quote from your answer, that was completely irrelevant to the question. The question was about "2 divided by 3".